# Openstack CLI throwing SSL error

Tags: python, openstack

I have installed Openstack CLI and when I try to use any command say

```
openstack server list
```

it is throwing the below error

```
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting
https://44.128.19.51:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
SSL exception connecting to https://44.128.19.51:5000/v3/auth/tokens:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
(_ssl.c:765)
```

I tried setting the export `OS_CACERT=/path/to/ca.crt`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a proper authorization `url`. Sometimes the port of the `url` can be wrong. Like in my case, the authorization `url` had port `1300` instead of `5000`.

And have you sourced your `RC` file?

Other than for proper authorization url, proper `CACERT` path or proper authorization certificates it should show this error.

Answer (score 0):

A long time has passed since the question, but if someone like myself faces the problem, enter the "OpenStack" command with the flag "--insecure".

Here's the related [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/man/openstack.html).